# "ProgrammingError at '/blog/'" on Heroku

Tags: python, django, sqlite, heroku

Finished an app and was about to deploy on Heroku before I realized I could have worked with a Virtual Env earlier. I created Virtualenv anyway and deployed on Heroku. Everything works well except for the blog page. I keep getting:

`ProgrammingError at '/blog/'  relation 'blog_post ' does not exist".`

Meanwhile it works just fine on the local server. I don't know if this is an Sqlite-Heroku bug or a Django version thing (App is written in the local django 3.0 but 3.0.8 is installed in the virtual env).

[image]

Comment: Can you show the full SQL query as well as the tables of your database?

Comment: `from django.db import models
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140) 
    body = models.TextField()  
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title `

Comment: Sorry it's muddled up. I could send a screenshot but it doesn't look like I can attach pictures to comments

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text (not image) In question (not in comment) - it will be more readable and more people will see it (so more people may help you)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, you have not migrated your `models.py` file to DB. Run `python manage.py migrate` on heroku & it should work fine. You don't need to run `python manage.py makemigrations` because you should be already having migrations on project folder.

Comment: When I tried that on heroku I got an error: `Warning: manage.py is not a heroku command.` then `Error: Run heroku help for a list of available commands`

Comment: Run `heroku run python manage.py migrate` from CMD. Make sure you are at correct project folder where `manage.py` file is there.

Comment: Says: `no migrations to apply` and `no changes detected`. Will you suggest I roll back on heroku, to the part where I'm to attach a database?

Comment: yes..give a try... have you created superuser & able to view admin page?

Comment: Thanks. I can add blog posts directly from the admin page as a superuser unfortunately the posts in the local admin are not showing. Heroku can't read them for some reason.

Comment: This might help you,.  https://youtu.be/6DI_7Zja8Zc

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved this!
The initial issue was that the blog posts I created locally in the Django app were not showing after I deployed to heroku. Many suggested that it had something to do with migrations. Yes, at first glance but I couldn't really tell.
So I decided to ditch the default SQLite3 that is native to Django (since it's not recommended for production) for the more stable PostgreSQL.
I dumped the SQLite database to PostgreSQL and ran migrations while deploying to heroku. But I had to still create another superuser which meant the local DB remained local. So I resorted to backing up the DB and import to heroku as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import).
I then made a psql dump file with:

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myPSQLuserName myPSQLdb > mydb.dump
```

Then I created a bucket on AWS S3 service and I uploaded 'mydb.dump' there because for PG Backups to access and import the dump file, you will need to upload it somewhere with an HTTP-accessible URL.
Then I ran:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore '<SIGNED URL>' DATABASE_URL
```

Meanwhile, I had granted public access in 'Permission' on the AWS bucket menu. Ran into some issues before this.
Then I added this to my settings.py as per AWS recommendation. I had installed django-storages and boto3 before this:

```
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITTE = False 
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None 
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

I loaded the heroku app and all is good now. The backup worked.